# Multiple keyword search with Java & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to write a Java code snippet to return the keywords contained in the description of a specific entity & SELECT only those records that contain both keywords.

The following code works, however it returns entities whose body contains only one or the other of the words. I need it to return only those records that contain both keywords, not just one of them.

```
try {         
    String search = txt_search.getText(); 
    search = search.trim(); 
    search = search.replace (' ','|');                                     
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM catagory WHERE keywords REGEXP '" + search + "'";         
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);                          
    rs = pst.executeQuery();                   
    if (rs.next()){                          
      String add1 = rs.getString("CatagoryId");                   
      txt_catagoryid.setText(add1);             
      String add2 = rs.getString("CatagoryName");                
      txt_catagoryName.setText(add2);             
      String add3 = rs.getString("keywords");             
      txt_keywords.setText(add3);                                
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);          
      catagoryTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));            
} catch(Exception e){
...
}
```

Comment: Also, its category, not catagory. But anyway - instead of searching via regex, just search for both the keywords together. eg, `where keywords = "keyword1 keyword2" or keywords="keyword2 keyword1"`. or something.

Comment: '|' is an **or** in regex, not an **and**